# How to use the OnPaint event in C#?

Tags: c#, events, onpaint

i saw some similar questions on the site but none of them really helped me.

I have a function that draws a few lines on the form when a button is clicked that vary in shape depending on the values the user enters in some textboxes.

My problem is that when i minimize the form, the lines disappear and i understood that this can be resolved by using the OnPaint event, but i don't really understand how.

Can anyone give me a simple example of using a function to draw something at the push of a button using the OnPaint event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here you go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), simpe MSDN tutorial on User-Drawn Controls

You must inherit `Button` class and override OnPaint method.

Code example:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
   // Call the OnPaint method of the base class.
   base.OnPaint(pe);

   // Declare and instantiate a new pen.
   System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Aqua);

   // Draw an aqua rectangle in the rectangle represented by the control.
   pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, new Rectangle(this.Location, 
      this.Size));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Add property to your class and like `public Color MyFancyTextColor {get;set;}` and use it in your `OnPaint` method. Alsow it will apear in control property editor of visual studio form designer.

Comment: But if i do this and i put my drawing function in the OnPaint method, how do i pass the values for the function's parameters from the form?

Comment: Ok, i did it, but i still have a problem : everytime the mouse cursor hovers over the buttons, the OnPaint method is called. How can i make it so that it ignores buttons?

Answer (score 3):

You can write all the code responsible for (re)drawing the scene into method called when `Paint` event occurs.

So, you can register you method to be called when Paint occurs like this:

```
this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(YourMethod);
```

Then YourMethod will be called whenever the form needs to be redrawn.

Also remember that you method must have the same arguments as delegate, in this case:

```
void YourMethod(object sender, PaintEventArgs pea)
{
   // Draw nice Sun and detailed grass
   pea.Graphics.DrawLine(/* here you go */);
}
```

### EDIT

Or, as mentioned in another answer, you can override `OnPaint` method. Then you don't have to take care about adding event handler with your own method.

Comment: So if i put my drawing function in YourMethod, everytime the form needs to be redrawn, it will call the function? If so, how do i get the parameters for my function?

Comment: Yes, it will. You don't need to take extra care about the arguments, because they are passed to YourMethod by runtime.